# problems getting session from ServletRequest in Filter

Tags: java, session, servlets, servlet-filters

My goal is to intercept the ServletResponse with a Filter and add some custom html to it before it gets displayed on the web page.  I also want to do some calculations and add the results to a session variable HashMap that I will be able to access in a subsequent call.

I can't figure out how to get the session from the ServletRequest inside doFilter method.  Here is my code:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {    
    CountingServletResponse counter = null;
    try {           
        HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        counter = new CountingServletResponse(httpResp);
        counter.addHeader("UniqueId", String.valueOf(counter.getUniqueId()));
        HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = httpReq.getSession(); //this throws error
        //I want to add session variable here
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        counter.flushBuffer(); // Push the last bits containing HTML comment.   
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The line with getSession throws

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the
>   response has been committed

and if I do getSession(false), then it makes it past that line but session == null and I can't add any session variables.
Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`getSession()` tries to get current session, and if it doesn't exist it tries to create a new one. `getSession(false)` also tries to get the session, but if one doesn't exist then it returns null (btw that means that `getSession() === getSession(true)`). That's why with `getSession()` you have exception (because you can't create one) and with `getSession(false)` you have `null`, because there is no session and no attempt to create a new one.

Since you are already sending response to the client, you can't add new http headers to it, it's too late at that point. Don't know what is your environment here, but you need to the necessary work sooner.

Comment: I understand about getSession() and getSession(false).  But response is not sent to the client until the chain.doFilter command.  I should be able to add session variables before then.

Comment: I was trying to make this post as simple as possible with only relevant code.  Turned out the problem was in another piece of code that was doing a flushBuffer to get the size of the response.  Apparently that killed the session as well.  Not sure how to include the size of the response in the response if this is the case.